# Let $G=\mathbb{Z_{10}}\times \mathbb{Z_{15}}$. Then find the number of elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Z_{10}}\times \mathbb{Z_{15}}$. Then,

1. $G$ contains exactly one element of order $2$.
2. $G$ contains exactly $5$ element of order $3$.
3. $G$ contains exactly $24$ element of order $5$.
4. $G$ contains exactly $24$ element of order $10$.

I know how to calculate number of elements when **external direct product** of groups is given. But in this case I don't know how to proceed. Please give me some hints. Thanks.

Comment: 1. This *is* an external direct product.  2. The title and body disagree (or did, until janmarqz changed the body).

Comment: Please specify what you mean by an external direct product, and why this isn't one.

Comment: Sorry actually I got caught in the notations, this is indeed the external direct product.

Comment: It might be useful to exploit that this is isomorphic to, e.g., $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_5 \times \Bbb Z_5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If the element $a \in \mathbb Z_{10}$ has order $A$ and the element $b \in \mathbb Z_{15}$ has order $B$ then the order of the element $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z_{10} \times \mathbb Z_{15}$ is the least-common-multiple of $A$ and $B$.

So in order that $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z_{10} \times \mathbb Z_{15}$ has order $2$ we must have $A,B \le 2$. But if $A=B=1$ then $(a,b) = (0,0)$ has order $1$. So either $\{A,B\} = \{2,1\}$ or $\{A,B\} = \{2\}$. Now look at each of $\mathbb Z_{10} $ and $\mathbb Z_{15}$ to determine what $a$ and $b$ can be.